# How to run jobs not dependent on each other while using a loop

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

**Scenario as follows**

cicd.yml file calls a template build-deploy-cicd.yml in a loop

**Problem:**
Multiple jobs are called but a depdency is set automatically that means if condition is not true then it effectively doesn't run the template twice and skips

**cicd.yml**

```
parameters: 
  - name: services
    type: object
    default: 
    - service1
    - service2

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: templates
      type: git
      name: aks-build-deploy-templates/common-build-deploy-templates
      ref: refs/heads/main

    - repository: service1
      type: git
      name: dotnet-ofg/service1
      ref: refs/heads/main

    - repository: service2
      type: git
      name: dotnet-ofg/service2
      ref: refs/heads/main

    
  - ${{ each service in parameters.services }}: 
    - template: pipelines/templates/build-deploy-cicd.yml@templates
      parameters: 
        pathToPackage: ${{ service }}
```

**build-deploy-cicd.yml**

```
parameters:
  - name: pathToPackage
    default: ""
stages:
- stage: one_${{ parameters.pathToPackage }}
  jobs:
  - job: A
    steps:
    - checkout: self
    - checkout: service1
    - checkout: service2
      persistCredentials: true
      fetchDepth: 0
    - bash: |
          echo "pathToPackage ${{ parameters.pathToPackage }}"
          ls -lhr
    - bash: |
          pathToPackage=${{ parameters.pathToPackage }}
          git diff HEAD~:src/${{ parameters.pathToPackage }} HEAD:src/${{ parameters.pathToPackage }}  --exit-code --quiet
          if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then 
              echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=skipsubsequent1;isOutput=true]true"
          else
              echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=skipsubsequent1;isOutput=true]false"
          fi
      name: skipstep
    
- stage: two_${{ parameters.pathToPackage }}
  dependsOn: one_${{ parameters.pathToPackage }}
  condition: eq(dependencies.one.outputs['A-${{ parameters.pathToPackage }}.skipstep.skipsubsequent1'], 'true')
  jobs:
  - job: B
    variables:
      skipMe1: $[stageDependencies.one.A-${{ parameters.pathToPackage }}.outputs['skipstep.skipsubsequent1']] 
    steps:
    - task: Bash@3
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          echo $(skipMe1)
```

When i try to run the pipeline cicd.yml,

Azure DevOps interprets as below

one_service1 (please note i had to construct distinguished job names using parameters)
no dependency

two_service1
depends on one_service1

one_service2
depends on two_service1

two_service2
depends on one_service2

I have tried to call the jobs individually but when running pipeline it creates 4 stages with dependencies stated above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, your problem is that `one_service2` depends on `two_service1`?

If that is indeed the case, you can update the `build-deploy-cicd.yml` to include `dependsOn: []` for the `one_service` stage.

That will update **build-deploy-cicd.yml** like so:

```
parameters:
  - name: pathToPackage
    default: ""
stages:
- stage: one_${{ parameters.pathToPackage }}
  dependsOn: []
  jobs:
  - job: A
    steps:
    - checkout: self
    - checkout: service1
    - checkout: service2
      persistCredentials: true
      fetchDepth: 0
    - bash: |
          echo "pathToPackage ${{ parameters.pathToPackage }}"
          ls -lhr
    - bash: |
          pathToPackage=${{ parameters.pathToPackage }}
          git diff HEAD~:src/${{ parameters.pathToPackage }} HEAD:src/${{ parameters.pathToPackage }}  --exit-code --quiet
          if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then 
              echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=skipsubsequent1;isOutput=true]true"
          else
              echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=skipsubsequent1;isOutput=true]false"
          fi
      name: skipstep
    
- stage: two_${{ parameters.pathToPackage }}
  dependsOn: one_${{ parameters.pathToPackage }}
  condition: eq(dependencies.one.outputs['A-${{ parameters.pathToPackage }}.skipstep.skipsubsequent1'], 'true')
  jobs:
  - job: B
    variables:
      skipMe1: $[stageDependencies.one.A-${{ parameters.pathToPackage }}.outputs['skipstep.skipsubsequent1']] 
    steps:
    - task: Bash@3
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          echo $(skipMe1)
```